# Blank page after deployment using surge

Tags: reactjs, surge.sh

I accidentally set wrongly my React's project path when deploying myapp using surge. And now I can just visualize an empty black page, even when specifying the project path correctly.

Has anyone solved this issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Give more context to your question that question is not reproduce able... [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: It might not be you. I just noticed that right now Surge appears to deploy my project correctly but all I can download from the deployed domain are 0 length files.

Comment: I had the same problem. I reached out to Surge and they replied back that it was a problem on their end and they fixed it.

Comment: Yes, that could be the reason. It's working perfectly now. Thanks